# getting fieldname from multiple tables depending on condition

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql, database, join

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT 
  u.ID,
  u.StudentCode,
  c.classname,
  s.STUDENTNAME,
  u.UserCode,
  g.ForeName AS MessageSentBy,
  u.Message,
  u.ForTchrSname AS MessageSentTo,
  DATE_FORMAT(u.datetime, '%d-%m-%y') AS datesent,
  u.RecordStatus 
FROM
  tblupdates u,
  tblguardian g,
  tblstudent s,
  tblclass c 
WHERE u.UserCode = g.GuardianCode 
  AND u.StudentCode = s.STUDENTCODE 
  AND (
    YEAR(u.DateTime) = '2013' 
    AND MONTH(u.DateTime) = '09'
  ) 
  AND u.RecordStatus = 'N' 
  AND c.classcode = s.classcode 
ORDER BY u.datetime DESC
```

Result of this query is shown below:
[image]

Now in my tblupdates for year-2013 and month-09 i have the following rows:
[image]

Now in my above result i am getting data for `id=138` but i want to display all.The reason for not displaying other rows is that `(usercode-30000,admin)` these occur in `tblteacher` rather than `tblguardian`.So now i want that if the `usercode` is from `tblguardian` it shows guardian name but if it is from `tblteacher` it shows `teachername` but shows all the rows.Tblteacher and tblupdates can be joined by teachercode and usercode respectively.

I tried the following query but it doesnot return any row:

```
SELECT 
  u.ID,
  u.StudentCode,
  c.classname,
  s.STUDENTNAME,
  u.UserCode,
  IF(
    u.usercode NOT IN (g.guardiancode),
    t.teachername,
    g.ForeName
  ) AS MessageSentBy,
  u.Message,
  u.ForTchrSname AS MessageSentTo,
  DATE_FORMAT(u.datetime, '%d-%m-%y') AS datesent,
  u.RecordStatus 
FROM
  tblupdates u,
  tblguardian g,
  tblstudent s,
  tblclass c,
  tblteacher t 
WHERE u.UserCode = g.GuardianCode 
  AND u.StudentCode = s.STUDENTCODE 
  AND t.teachercode = u.usercode 
  AND (
    YEAR(u.DateTime) = '2013' 
    AND MONTH(u.DateTime) = '09'
  ) 
  AND u.RecordStatus = 'N' 
  AND c.classcode = s.classcode 
ORDER BY u.datetime DESC
```

Please help me out

Comment: An outer join should do the trick, in mysql, left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with using `CASE` and i have joined you tables using `LEFT` join so there can be duplicates i have use `GROUP BY` also by `u.id` but bit confused for right column name please put the right column in group by

```
SELECT 
  u.ID,
  u.StudentCode,
  c.classname,
  s.STUDENTNAME,
  u.UserCode,  
  (CASE 
  WHEN u.usercode = t.teachercode THEN t.teachername 
  WHEN u.usercode = g.guardiancode THEN g.ForeName 
  ELSE END ) AS MessageSentBy,
  u.Message,
  u.ForTchrSname AS MessageSentTo,
  DATE_FORMAT(u.datetime, '%d-%m-%y') AS datesent,
  u.RecordStatus 
FROM
  tblupdates u
  LEFT JOIN  tblguardian g ON (u.UserCode = g.GuardianCode )
  LEFT JOIN  tblstudent s ON (u.StudentCode = s.STUDENTCODE )
  LEFT JOIN  tblclass c ON (c.classcode = s.classcode )
  LEFT JOIN   tblteacher t  ON (t.teachercode = u.usercode)
WHERE   u.RecordStatus = 'N' 
 AND  (
    YEAR(u.DateTime) = '2013' 
    AND MONTH(u.DateTime) = '09'
  )  
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.datetime DESC
```

Comment: thanx...it worked for me.But can we achieve the same by some small query or other way.

Comment: Joins are our best friends and i thinks we cannot short this query it only has two conditions with joins only

Comment: and if we want to do offline filtering whether it will be fast than this or will take same time

Comment: and in the above query if i am using distinct(u.studentcode) it is showing error..can you tell me why

Comment: If there are multiple columns in select then you cannot use `DISTINCT` for single column and distinct should be place before first column without braces thats why i added the group by

Comment: ya.Actually i want to show my results in a page in such a manner that for a particular month and year,for each student all the conversation of his parents and teacher is shown date wise but i am unable to get the desired result.can you suggest some way